# Forms, separate div for labels and inputs

Tags: html, forms

Is this correct to have separate div for inputs and separate div for labels?
For example:

```
<div class="labels">
     <label for="place-name">Place name: </label>
     <label for="place-cat">Category: </label>
</div>

<div class="inputs">
     <input type="text" name="place-name">
     <select name="place-cat">
          <option value="value-01">Value 01</option>
          <option value="value-02">Value-02</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it depends on how you want to use these div tags.

Comment: Just for styling purpose. Labels on left side, inputs on right side. Two column layout.

Comment: thats why 'for' attribute is invented =)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this 

<style>
.clear{
clear:both;
margin:5px;
padding:5px 0px;
}
.labels{
float:left;
width:100px;
}
.inputs{
float:left;
}
</style>

<div class="clear">
<div class="labels"><label for="place-name">Place name: </label></div>
<div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="place-name"></div>
</div>

<div class="clear">
<div class="labels"><label for="place-cat">Category: </label></div>
<div class="inputs"><select name="place-cat">
          <option value="value-01">Value 01</option>
          <option value="value-02">Value-02</option>
     </select></div>
</div>
```