# How to style checkbox where check box and label in separate div sections

Tags: html, css

I have created separate div sections for checkbox and label and I want style checkbox. When use only checkbox and label it will work properly, but When add div sections it won't work. I tried solutions in this forum but those solutions are not working please anyone can check and help me on this

[How to Checkbox and label style only with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909127/how-to-checkbox-and-label-style-only-with-css)
[Forms, separate div for labels and inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663413/forms-separate-div-for-labels-and-inputs)

```css
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] + .checkmark label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox  input[type=checkbox] + .checkmark label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] + .checkmark label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkmark label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:disabled + .checkmark label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled + .checkmark label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple">
</div>
  <div>
    <label for="fruit1" class="checklabel">Apple</label>
</div>
```

Comment: In css your class name is `checkcon` and in html you have `checkbox` ??

Comment: please Sir now check it

Comment: Will you please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error `checkcon` to `checbox` or Change Some HTML Position

```css
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] +  label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox  input[type=checkbox] +  label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox  input[type=checkbox] + label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox  input[type=checkbox]:disabled +  label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.checkbox  input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled +  label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple">
    <label for="fruit1" class="checklabel">Apple</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I changed checkcon to checbox but I want checkbox and label in separate sections

Comment: `but I want checkbox and label in separate sections` need to use some jquery

Comment: We are not able to achieve this through CSS

Comment: `We are not able to achieve this through CSS` no

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same class for the checkbox input

```
<input class="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
    }
});
```

```css
.checkbox + .checkmark label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox  + .checkmark label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

.checkbox + .checkmark label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox.selected + .checkmark label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox] + .checkmark label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkmark label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple">    </div>
  <div class="checkmark">
    <label for="fruit1" class="checklabel">Apple</label>
</div>
```